# Swift - Modifying a variable with the variable name stored in a variable

Tags: swift

The title of this question is most probably confusing but I have no idea what to name this question. I am writing a program in swift and I want to modify a property of an object (in this case a UIImageView) but I'm not sure of which object I'm going to modify, I only know the type.

An example of what I'm talking about is shown below:

*Inside the ViewController class*

```
@IBOutlet weak var LeftImage: UIImageView!
@IBOutlet weak var RightImage: UIImageView!


// A function to change the image inside a UIImageView
func ChangeImage(imageViewLocation: UIImageView, newImage: String) {
    // Change the image
    self.imageViewLocation.image = UIImage(named: newImage))
}


// Call the function
ChangeImage(LeftImage, "smileyFace")
```

Can this be done?

Comment: you can try the reflection API. search for `Mirror`

Comment: What error do you get?

Comment: remove self from the function

Comment: I have no idea what you want to do... What do you want your code to do - Check UIImageView being passed, updated the image of a UIImageView? By the way, don't capitalise your method and variable names - it's bad practice (e.g. leftImage instead of LeftImage) and don't refer to self.imageViewLocation, because you don't have the variable in that scope - simply use imageViewLocation.image...

Comment: Thanks @ogres That was it

Comment: Just a note: please use lowercase function and variable names.